# Setting option value from database value Newbie

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I am trying to use a dropdown list and set the value to the one in the databse.

For example if the database holds "Website" I would want this to be the selected option on the dropdown form.

See below code, I have repeated this for each of my products

```
if($product['product'] = 'Website'){
echo"
<div class='form-group'>
<label for='mail_message'>Product<font color='red'>*</font></label>
<select name='product' id='product' class='form-control' required>
<option value='Website'  selected='selected'>Website</option>
<option value='CMS'>CMS</option>
<option value='Domain'>Domain</option>
<option value='Hosting'>Hosting</option>
</select>
</div>
"; }
```

When i run this code, i have numerous dropdowns showing with each of my products showing as the selected value for each

Can anyone help? (NB)

Comment: please add some more of your code, for example the code that gives you the results(sql code) and basicly everything that can have something to do with this, also since you are talking about a database a tiny bit more information about how the database looks like would be handy

Comment: You need to construct the <option...> line to either have `selected` or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i am correct then you want to target the results from the database that has "website" in them right?

then you have to edit your sql query to only select those so the query would become something like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM `table_name` FROM `database_name` WHERE `type`='website'"
```

please do note that you have to replace 'table_name' to the actual table name,
database_name to the actual database name and 'type' to the actual table key.

if the query is like this then you wont have to check if($product['product'] = 'Website') because this would always be true